# Rails a/an inflector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, view-helpers, inflector

Is there a built-in Rails inflector for determining if a word starts with a vowel? I have this (HAML):

```
  -if @user.aquire_deploy_text.match /^[aeiou]/i
    an
  -else
    a
  #{@user.aquire_deploy_text}.
```

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: There are [gems](https://github.com/rossmeissl/indefinite_article).

Comment: you can use this method word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u')

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari What about uppercase vowels?

Comment: Then you can try word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')